# Xml.Serialization multiple types for an object

Tags: c#, xml

I have this `Property` and want to use it like this:

```
public class XmlValue : INullable
{
    [XmlElement("IpAdress", typeof(IpClass))]
    [XmlElement("FileValue", typeof(FileClass))]
    [XmlElement("StringValue", typeof(string))]
    public object Value { get; set; }

    public bool IsNull => Value == null;
}
```

So there are different fields in my nested Xml-Class for `public object Value`.
But there will be only one of the possibles elements (`IpAdress`,`FileValue` and `StringValue`) available at once.

The actual code just kills my object deserialization with null.

How can I make it work that i only need one property?

Comment: Please show a [mcve] containing of example data and usage of this class, also show what else you have tried. Why does it have to be one `object Value`? Why can't it be three separate, non-required properties, which you expose from a getter which returns the first non-null value from those three properties? Of course I'm thinking about _deserialization_ here. Anyway it always helps to start designing this from an XSD, not code. How would you express what you want to do in an XSD?

Answer (score 1):

Use three different classes with `IpClass`, `FileClass` and `string` field. Otherwise You should customize serialization

Use attribute `[XmlInclude(typeof(YourClass))]` on base class to declare dirived classes.

```
[XmlInclude(typeof(IpClass))]
[XmlInclude(typeof(FileClass))]
[XmlInclude(typeof(StringValue))]
public abstract class AbstractValue : INullable
{   
    public virtual bool IsNull => Value == null;
}
public sealed class IpValue : AbstractValue
{   
    public IpClass Value { get; set; }
}
public sealed class FileValue : AbstractValue
{   
    public FileClass Value { get; set; }
}
public sealed class StringValue : AbstractValue
{   
    public string Value { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: I dont use a base class for this.

Comment: @Peter, I see, but You should use

Comment: Why should I - if I can have object?

Comment: `object` is kind of hack in this case, but default serialization cannot define object, so cannot process this object. That's why You have two way: own serialization or replace object with real class

Comment: Are you not simply reinventing `Nullable<T>` here? How is this meaningfully different?

Comment: @Flater, actually he is reinventing List<object>, but any way it cannot be serialized as is